# TTC fonts support

Tags: fonts

Can Ubuntu(or linux) properly support .ttc font format?

I have copied from my Windows 7 partition to Ubuntu 10.04 some fonts, including entire Cambria family, but it seems like default Cambria version with .ttc extension cannot be displayed in linux. LibreOffice recognizes Cambria fonts, but i cannot select default version, only Italic, Bold and Bold Italic which are .ttf

Download and try it for yourself, maybe i am doing something wrong.
http://www.mediafire.com/?lc319rgolrywa35

Comment: Why don't you instead install each of the family's separate font?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: this is a valid question and I am facing the same problem. found an answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/387367/101263)

Answer (score 0):

Check the file ~/.fonts.conf to see if the default Cambria font is rejected. (Probably you can just delete this file).