# Cambria appears only in italics in LibreOffice

Tags: 12.04, fonts, libreoffice

I have a Windows 7 partition mounted in Ubuntu. In order to access the fonts I created a link to the Windows font folder using

```
ln -s /path/to/your/windows/fonts/folder .fonts/windows
```

I then refreshed my font cache using

```
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

I only get Cambria in italics in LibreOffice. All the versions are available in gedit. Is there a way to get the regular and bold versions too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular (upright) style of Cambria is in the TrueType Collection (.ttc) format, allowing it to contain several styles in one file (in this case, Cambria and Cambria Math).

Since version 4.3.3 (released in 2014), LibreOffice is now compatible with TTC fonts when running on Linux. [This is the commit](https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/gitweb?p=core.git;a=commitdiff;h=02f8f895f2abc4ee090b4bd42963590aa018fb49) that implements that support. Therefore, the workaround described in the accepted answer is no longer needed.

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/how-to-download-and-install-windows-81.html

> If you need the Cambria (regular) font, you'll need to convert it to
>   TTF because the font is available as a TrueType Collection (TTC) and
>   unless you convert it, you won't be able to use it in LibreOffice for
>   instance. To convert it to TTF, you need to install FontForge:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install fontforge
> ```
>
> And then, open a terminal and run the following command (the commands
>   below assume you've followed our exact instructions and extracted the
>   fonts under ~/sources/fonts):
>
> ```
> cd ~/sources/fonts/ 
> fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open("cambria.ttc(Cambria)"); Generate("cambria.ttf");Close();Open("cambria.ttc(Cambria Math)"); Generate("cambria-math.ttf");Close();'
> ```